# jQuery ajax process request from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So i am kinda new to jquery with ajax.  Basically, the page send an http post, and the server side dll, writes a response to the page in json format.  I am trying to figure out how to process a response this response.  So far when I got to the website and fill in all the information, and hit submit, it then post to a iis webserver page and process the request and serializes into json format and does  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write back to the page.   The page just now displays the text in json format.

How do i capture this response do stuff with the data and present it to the screen in a more readable format.  I need to do this isn jquery /ajax format on all one page.

Below is my fully html code.  most of the java script is from an example i found:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
// variable to hold request
var request;
// bind to the submit event of our form
$("#frmLookup").submit(function(event){
// abort any pending request
if (request) {
    request.abort();
}
// setup some local variables
var $form = $(this);
// let's select and cache all the fields
var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
// serialize the data in the form
var serializedData = $form.serialize();
// let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
$inputs.prop("disabled", true);

// fire off the request to /form.php
request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://server1/RWebService/users",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});

// callback handler that will be called on success
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR, json){
    // log a message to the console
    console.write("HELLO WORLD");

});

// callback handler that will be called on failure
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // log the error to the console
    console.error(
        "The following error occured: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});

// callback handler that will be called regardless
// if the request failed or succeeded
request.always(function () {
    // reenable the inputs
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
});

// prevent default posting of form
event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</head>

 <body>
    Look up user

    <form id="frmLookup" name="input" action = "http://server1/RWebService/users" method = "post" >
    BWS HostName:  <input type="text" name="wBWSHostName" value="foobar.com" />
    <BR>
    UserName:  <input type="text" name="wBWSUserName" value="admin" />
    <br />
    Password:  <input type="password" name="wBWSPassword" value="password"/>
    <BR>
    Lookup User: <input type="text" name="wUser" value="foo@bar.com"/>
    <input type="submit" name="wLookup" value="Lookup" />

    </form>

    <div id="data">

    </div>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

User the callback `done` to process the `response` and do the job in the page.

Edit: I have create a small fiddle to show you how an ajax is intended to behave. You can take it as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jvzn5/

Comment: Can you give me an example?  right now all the data is shown in json format on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you aren't actually submitting the form itself by using a submit button, etc. You only want to post the form's data via the jQuery.

Change:

```
<input type="submit"
```

To:

```
<input type="button" id="lookup-button"
```

to prevent the form from being submitted.

Then:

```
$("#frmLookup").submit(...
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#lookup-button").click(...
  ...
  ...
});
```

Note: you will need an extra }); at the end to close the ${document).ready(function(){ which is saying, after the DOM loads, wire up my button's click event with all the stuff in there.

This way your button is submitting the request. Previously, the button click was doing both things.

Then, you'd need to handle the result, as Joqus mentioned, but we'd need to know what the JSON you are returning looks like. In general, though, you should be able to do something like response.MyProp or response.MyObject.MyProp in done().

Comment: What do you mean my sbumitting the form itself by using submit button,  Dd you mean in my html code <form id="ftmLookup" name="input" action = "http://server1/RWebService/users" method = "post" >  Do i need to remove this part?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to remove anything, but if you are only posting via jQuery, you don't really need the action, method attributes. See my edited response for more details.

Comment: So i changed my submit to type button.  So my $.ajax code isn't actually submitting the post request.

Comment: When i click the lookup button nothing happens.

Comment: When using ajax, the intention is not to load a new page. Just to get data and use it inside the page. Check the network tab in you browser to see if a request is being trigerred.

Comment: That's a good point, too. @user1158745, are you sure you really want to do this via ajax? What do you intend to do after the data posts to your server side code?

Comment: So i must be doing something wrong with the from because id="lookup-button" never get's triggered.

Comment: Can you get at your browser's console to look for errors? There were a lot of changes made, so I'm guessing there's a syntax error somewhere.